# gstreamer get length of media from console

Tags: mp3, gstreamer, content-length

I want to retrieve the time length of a MP3 file with gstreamer with a command on the console. But I don't know how.

I tried the following command

```
gst-launch filesrc location=$myMediaFile ! decodebin2 ! fakesink
```

but I got the following result:

---

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...

Pipeline is PREROLLING ...

Pipeline is PREROLLED ...

Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...

New clock: GstSystemClock

Got EOS from element "pipeline0".

Execution ended after 370731000 ns.

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...

Setting pipeline to READY ...

Setting pipeline to NULL ...

Freeing pipeline .

---

The time 370731000ns does not correspond to the time of the media which was 86 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have gst-discoverer you can get time length with this command line:
gst-discoverer-0.10 -v $myMediaFile